# How do I select an element only when inside another element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a question regarding CSS selectors. How do I select a `<div>` with a specific class name only when its inside a `<ul>` with a class name `saft`?  This CSS class is used elsewhere and I don't want to change the styling everywhere.

```
<div id="floater">
    <ul class="saft">
        <li><div class="textSlide"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Simply use the CSS descendant selector (a space) between the parent element and the descendant element:

```
ul.saft div.textSlide {
    /* CSS rules */
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.saft div.textSlide {
  background-color: #f90;
  font-weight: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="saft">
  <li>
    <div class="textSlide">Some text in a textSlide class element</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="textSlide">Some more text, also in a textSlide element</div>
```

In this case the rules applied to the `div` of class `textSlide` will only apply if its ancestor is a `ul` of the class `saft`. You could, instead, use the immediate child combinator, the `>` but then you'd have to specify the `div` in relation to each parent/ancestor up to the one whose class is required, which gives potentially difficult to maintain CSS (not in this case, but it can, over time, become problematic).

Comment: Thanks for that works perfectly...gotta wait for a couple of min before I can accept....but I will, Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can we do the same with IDs?

Comment: @Jas: of course, `#ancestor #descendant` would select, and style, the element with the id of “descendant” if it was found within the element of id “ancestor,” although this is of limited use since an `id` must be unique within the document, and only helps if an ancestor element may change in some way.

Comment: This not applies the styles to the parent element. How to apply that styles to the parent element? So <div class="1"><div class="2"></div></div><div class="1"></div> Thinmk the class="2" has a margin to class="1" and that I want is to put a border in the parent div (class="1")

Comment: I was looking for :has

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

`ul.saft .textSlide {`

This achieves what you need

Comment: This styles the UL not the div.textslide

Answer (score 0):

you can easily select a div with a specific class name only when its inside a UL with a class name saft like mentioned below css :-

```
ul.saft .textSlide {
color:red;
}
```

or see the demo :- http://tinkerbin.com/mcrh7iMq