# I can't understand this type of css usage

Tags: css

It's odd but I can't understand the following css usage.

```
.containertable table
{
    ...
}
```

I know `table.containertable`      *which means  `class="containertable"`*

Comment: any table within class .containertable like: <div class="containertable "><table> .....

Answer (score 4):

It means this:

```
<div class='containertable'>
    <table> <!-- This table here or any other table under '.containertable' -->
        ....
```

Any table within the class `.containertable` will be effected by the CSS rules you put in `.containertable table {`.

It does not mean it is a direct descendant, just that any `table` element within `containertable` is effected.

This also includes:

```
<div class='containertable'>
    <div class='anotherClass'>
        <table> <!-- this is also effected by the CSS -->
```

Answer (score 2):

It will select all `table` elements which are inside an element with the class `containertable`

Also see: [CSS selectors Selecting an element only when inside another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863423/css-selectors-selecting-an-element-only-when-inside-another-element)

Answer (score 0):

`.containertable table { ... }` addresses:

```
<div class='containertable'>
  <table></table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not must be a direct descended it must be said

Answer (score 0):

This mean: all tables that has direct or indirect parent element of any type with class="containertable"

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp

It can be:

```
<div class="containertable">
 <table> </table>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="containertable">
 <h3> </h3>
 <table> </table>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="containertable">
  <div class="someclass">
     <table> </table>
  <div>
</div>
```

**but not:**

```
<table class="containertable">
</table>
```

or:

```
<table>
 <tr class="containertable"> </tr>
</table>
```